# Series convergence or divergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Determine whether this series converges:

$\Sigma e^{-j+sinj}$

I know that this series is $\leq$ than $\Sigma e^{-j+1}$, but I am having trouble getting this in a form appropriate for a convergence test...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For a geometric series with $|r|\lt1$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty ar^n=\frac{a}{1-r}
$$